# css - Angular mat-chip background is being change when focus on

Tags: css, angular

I'm using Angular mat-chip with a simple css style: `background-color white`.
it works properly, but when I focus on the element, the background color disappears.

```
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip  *ngFor="let value of list" style="background-color: white" 
    [removable]="true" (removed)="removeValue(value)">
    {{ value }}
     <mat-icon matChipRemove class="fs-12">close</mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
```

The normal state is:
[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWral.png)

On blur state is:
[blur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXifW.png)

Do you have any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [focus selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp) to update the background color.

```
mat-chip, mat-chip:focus {
   background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the background that is changed but rather the opacity. The below did it for me.

```
mat-chip:focus::after {
  opacity: 0;
}
```